# Integral of the Poisson Kernal

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, wolfram-alpha-queries

I wish to solve the following definite integral:

$\int^{b}_a P_r(\theta-\phi) d\phi$

,where $P_r(\theta-\phi) = \frac{1-r^2}{1 + r^2 -2r cos(\theta - \phi)}$ is the [Poisson kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel).  This is something I have come across while solving the Laplace equation on a unit disk in the context of electrostatics. The definite integral of this equation can be calculated and the solution obtained using Mathematica (and other online integral calculators) is given by:

$2 tan^{-1}\Big((\frac{1+r}{1-r})tan(\frac{\theta - \phi}{2})\Big) + constant$

[image]

. I believe that the definite integral is a bit tricky since the range of the inverse tangent function can be $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$, $[\pi/2, 3\pi/2]$,... and so on. When trying to find the definite integral of the same function using Mathematica or other tools, I keep getting the message that the computation time has exceeded. I assumed for a while that the integral might just be:

$2 tan^{-1}\Big((\frac{1+r}{1-r})tan(\frac{\theta - b}{2})\Big) - 2 tan^{-1}\Big((\frac{1+r}{1-r})tan(\frac{\theta - a}{2})\Big)$

, but I am not sure if it is the answer. I have used other online tools as well but all of them are giving the same error for some reason.

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ["Some kinds of questions are considered off-topic: Questions on Wolfram Alpha (but questions on using Wolfram Alpha within Mathematica are okay)."](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematica 13 does it under the natural assumptions:

```
Integrate[(1 - r^2)/(1 + r^2 - 2*r*Cos[\[Theta] - \[Phi]]), {\[Phi], a, b},
Assumptions -> r >= 0 && r < 1 && a > -Pi && a < b &&  b <= Pi && 
\[Theta] > -Pi && \[Theta] <= Pi]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[2*(ArcTan[((1 + r)*Tan[(a - \[Theta])/2])/(-1 + r)] - ArcTan[((1 + r)*Tan[(b - \[Theta])/2])/(-1 + r)]),  (b <= Pi + \[Theta] && \[Theta] <= 0) || a >= Pi + \[Theta] || (\[Theta] > 0 && (b + Pi < \[Theta] || a + Pi > \[Theta]))`

Answer (score 2):

Too long to post as comment:

Wolfram has timelimit. You can try the Pro version?

But it took 5 minutes on V 13. This is the answer

[image: Mathematica graphics]

code:

```
ClearAll[R, r, theta, phi]
integrand = (R^2 - r^2)/(R^2 + r^2 - 2*R*r*Cos[theta - phi])
Integrate[integrand, {theta, a, b}]
```

gives (note the conditions)

```
ConditionalExpression[2*(ArcTan[((r + R)*Tan[(a - phi)/2])/(r - R)] - ArcTan[((r + R)*Tan[(b - phi)/2])/(r - R)]), 
 r^2 + R^2 != 2*r*R*Cos[b - phi] && (Re[(r^2 + R^2 - 2*r*R*Cos[a - phi])/(r*R*Cos[a - phi] - r*R*Cos[b - phi])] < -2 || 
   Re[(r^2 + R^2 - 2*r*R*Cos[a - phi])/(r*R*Cos[a - phi] - r*R*Cos[b - phi])] > 0 || NotElement[(r^2 + R^2 - 2*r*R*Cos[a - phi])/(r*R*Cos[a - phi] - r*R*Cos[b - phi]), Reals]) && 
  (Re[(r^2 + R^2 - 2*r*R*Cos[b - phi])/(r*R*Cos[a - phi] - r*R*Cos[b - phi])] < 0 || Re[(r^2 + R^2 - 2*r*R*Cos[b - phi])/(r*R*Cos[a - phi] - r*R*Cos[b - phi])] > 2 || 
   NotElement[(r^2 + R^2 - 2*r*R*Cos[b - phi])/(r*R*Cos[a - phi] - r*R*Cos[b - phi]), Reals])]
```